# How to insert data to database using multiple array using POST method with ajax:

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I read similar answer here in this question: [How to insert into MYSQL row from multiple $_POST arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665208/how-to-insert-into-mysql-row-from-multiple-post-arrays) and [How to insert into MYSQL row from multiple $_POST arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665208/how-to-insert-into-mysql-row-from-multiple-post-arrays) but the problem is these answers do not work in my code. Is it because im using an ajax? and i only get the value of the first array.

If i also place the variable declaration inside the for loop it is not working too.

Here is my ajax:

```
var name = []; 
$('input[name="name[]"]').map(function(){ name.push($(this).val()); }); var studid = []; 
$('input[name="studid[]"]').map(function(){ studid.push($(this).val()); }); var nameStr = name != '' ? '&name='+ name : '';
var studStr = studid != '' ? '&studid='+ studid : '';
var dataString = 'subject='+ subject + '&section=' + section + studStr + nameStr;

$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: 'save.php', data: dataString, dataType: "html", 
success: function(data) {
    $('input#subject-field').val('');
    $('input#section-field').val('');
    $('input.record-input-forms').val('');
    $('#status-message').css({"color":"#39b1c6"});
    $('#status-message').html('Save successfully',function(){
    $('#status-message').fadeOut(2000); }); }, 
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    alert(thrownError); } });
    return false;
});
```

Here is my php:

```
if(isset($_POST['studid']) || isset($_POST['name'])){
    $studid = array_map(mysql_real_escape_string, explode(",",$_POST['studid']));
    $name = array_map(mysql_real_escape_string, explode(",",$_POST['name']));   

    for ($i=0; $i<count($studid); $i++){
        $sql_1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_student(StudentID, StudentName, SubjectID)  VALUES ('".$studid[$i]."', '".$name[$i]."', LAST_INSERT_ID())"; 
        mysqli_query($con,$sql_1);  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mysql_insert_id();
instead of LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: this is part of the solution i had, there is nothing wrong with the ajax. It was my bad, i set he subject id as foreign key in the table student.. I change my syntax last_insert_id() to that above and now it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending data correctly from the jQuery and its seems you'r mixing arrays and string together.

This is a simple request that posts studid-array from jQuery

```
var saveData = $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {studid: studid},
                    url: 'save.php',
                    dataType: 'html'
                });

saveData.done(function(data) {                                                   
    $('input#subject-field').val('');
    $('input#section-field').val('');
    $('input.record-input-forms').val('');
    $('#status-message').css({"color":"#39b1c6"});
    $('#status-message').html('Save successfully',function(){
    $('#status-message').fadeOut(2000); });

});                        

saveData.fail(function(ts) {
    alert(ts.responseText);
});
```

When save.php is called, `$_POST['studid']` would be set (if there are anything in the array)

If you instead do like this:

```
var saveData = $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'save.php?studid=' + studid,
                        dataType: 'html'
                    });
```

When save.php is called, `$_GET['studid']` would be set (if there are anything in the array). The best way though is to use data-option in the ajax-function call (in my first case). If you choose to use this option you would have to serialize the stuid-array before putting it in as a part of an url.

**UPDATE**
If you want to pass multiple arrays you would have to do something like this:

```
var saveData = $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {studid: studid, name_arr2: data_arr2},
                        url: 'save.php',
                        dataType: 'html'
                    });
```

Comment: thank you for the response, this was actually inrelation with my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665983/prevent-an-empty-form-input-from-submitting-an-empty-value-to-database-after-rem it is actually working if i only work with one array and foreach to loop with each array, there was no issue in sending the data to the database. Im just stumble down when i tried to add another array in my request which is the var $name.,since foreach can only handle one parameter so i tried using forloop but i cant figure it out.

Comment: If you have two array you want send with data-option just do like this: data: {name of arr1: data from arr1, name of arr2: data from arr2}

Comment: but how about my php is it coded right? im still new in using ajax, and im not yet that good. i was hoping a more straight forward answer. But thank you, i will try to configure the answers you provided. :)

Comment: @rigorcadiz - A more straightforward answer? "these answers do not work in my code.", "I only get the value of the first array.", "If i also place the variable declaration inside the for loop it is not working too.". ---- I see that your code is not working, but start from the basics... what do you want to achieve with your code?

Comment: i want to know, what im doing wrong with my codes above especially in php. Why i cant get the value of each array using a for loop, if im sending the data incorrectly from jquery/ajax then why it is working if use foreach? for instance if i will only use one array. I can save the value of each array from variable $studid alone.

Comment: And the links i provided in my question according to it i need to use for loop and use counter,  to get each value from the array but "those answers do not work in my code." and the last edited answer you provided that one works the same this as using the variable dataString in my code. isnt it?